# Nested routing and subscription in child on initOn in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have some app which use components to passing variable. There we decided to introduce a nested routing. The problem is the fact that child component need to subscribe before it will be navigated here.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', children: [
    { path: 'mainDataPanel', component: MainDataPaneComponent, outlet: 'mainPanel'}

  ] },
  { path: AppUrls.LoginComponentPath, component: LoginComponent }
];
```

My html looks:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    (...)
    <app-tree></app-tree>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button (...)
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
      >
      </button>
      (...)
      <button mat-button ><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { mainPanel: ['timeseries'] } }]">Simulation</a></button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet name="mainPanel"></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The user has to choose any node from sidenav and I should inform other components.

Component for communicate:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentInteractionsService {

  // Observable scenario sources
  private selectedNode = new Subject<TreeNode>();

  // Observable scenario streams
  selectedNode$ = this.selectedNodeSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  selectedNode(node: TreeNode) {
    this.selectedNodeSource.next(node);
  }
}
```

Finally:

my tree run after click at node:

```
this.componentInteractionsService.selectedNode(node);
```

The problem regarding to component which wont activated yet so There I won't subscribe to "stream":

```
export class MainDataPaneComponent implements OnInit {
private nodeGuid: string;

    constructor(private componentInteractionsService: ComponentInteractionsService) {
        (...)
        componentInteractionsService.selectedNode$.subscribe(n => this.nodeGuid = n.NodeGuid);
        console.log('test2');
      }

    ngOnInit() {
        componentInteractionsService.selectedScenario$.subscribe(n => this.nodeGuid = n.NodeGuid);
        console.log('test');
    }}
```

Currently I need to navigate to the component MainDataPaneComponent in order to activate it, then everything works (clicking on tree trigger actions).

How can I subscribe to stream in component which aren't activated or navigated to? That is possible to run constructor of components without explicit navigate to components?

Thank you for any answer